# Google calendar API not working on server

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to use Calendar API from my application and for that I have created client but it works in localhost only, it is not working on server. I follow steps given in [Google Calendar API dotnet](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet).

Can you please help me out with this.

Code is like.

```
    public List<CalendarEvent> GetEvents(long clientId)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        string pathResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../GoogleApiResponses/calendarRes_" + clientId + ".json");

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                _scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(pathResponse, true)).Result;
        }

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = _applicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var eventTrim = events.Items.Select(GetEventTrim).ToList();
            //events.Items[0].Id
            return eventTrim;
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<CalendarEvent>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code in your question. Also it's not clear what do you mean by "it works in localhost only not after publishing". Does it work on localhost or on server?

Comment: @YakovL I have edited my question, provided code and it is not working on server. It works fine on localhost.

Comment: did you add the redirect uri for the server in the Google Developer console?  Are you sure that the server has access to the PathResponse directory?  Is this Azure?

Comment: @DaImTo No I didn't add redirect uri, can you give me steps how I can add this? Yes server has access to the directory. No it is not azure.

Comment: Google developers console its in the setup their you must have added localhost.   Just add the server as well.   Its probably working its just trying to return the response to localhost which it shouldn't it should be sending it to the website URL

Comment: @DaImTo No I didn't add localhost I just follow steps given in the link I have provided and in that they didn't mention to add server url.

Comment: Localhost is probably default it will work for development now you need to go and edit it and add the server url.

Comment: What would be the Application type when we create Client, I have set Other and also tried with Web Application and also set redirect url for that but didn't work.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. From local I am able to Create, update, and GetEvents but from server I am able to  create event butt not get event. Any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com) edit the credentials and add the redirect URI for the server.

If you read the grayed out text it does tell you to do that.

[image]